# Another way to install emacs on OS X using homebrew

Tags: osx, build

It seems `homebrew` has removed all the options (incl. `--with-cocoa`) for `brew install emacs`. Now it recommends to use `brew cask install emacs` to get a built binary from https://emacsformacosx.com/. However, it is not clear to me which options are used to build the binary. The ones I care about are:

`--with-modules --with-cocoa --with-gnutls --with-librsvg`

Is there still a way to use `homebrew` to build the latest emacs but with the options above? If not possible, then how do we build emacs from source on OS X (10.12+) with those options

Answer (score 5):

Any Emacs can show you how it was configured at build-time. Inspect the value of `system-configuration-options` with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd>. A recent Emacs from https://emacsformacosx.com/ shows:

```
system-configuration-options is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
Its value is
"--with-ns '--enable-locallisppath=/Library/Application Support/Emacs/${version}/site-lisp:/Library/Application Support/Emacs/site-lisp' --with-modules"

Documentation:
String containing the configuration options Emacs was built with.
```

If that doesn't satisfy you, you can either do:

```
$ brew edit emacs
# make the changes you want
$ brew install -s emacs
```

or install emacs from its source at https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/emacs-26.1.tar.gz

Comment: If the Emacs is already installed after `brew edit emacs` run `brew reinstall -s emacs` rather than just `install`.

Answer (score 1):

You may install `emacs-plus` from [this](https://github.com/d12frosted/homebrew-emacs-plus):

From that link:

> Note that by default emacs-plus builds the Cocoa version of Emacs with
>   gnutls, imagemagick, librsvg and dynamic modules support by default.